# Subquery using Where not in in the same table with multiple columns doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 8.0.21

I am trying to calculate how many rows within a given table meet the necessary requirements. In this case, I want to count how many distinct 'student_id' rows there are in a 'class_id' per date, but I can only consider a 'student_id' if all the 'grade' of that 'student_id' equals 0. Also, I can only consider it if 'active' = TRUE.

for this query, I would expect a result like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVWAF.png)

Query to build database is here:

```
create table students (
    dt_reference DATE, 
    CLASS_ID number(10), 
    STUDENT_ID number(10), 
    GRADE number(10), 
    ACTIVE boolean
);

insert into students values ('2022-10-10', 1, 100, 10,TRUE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-10', 1, 100, 0,TRUE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-10', 1, 100, 0,TRUE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-11', 1, 100, 0,TRUE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-11', 1, 100, 0,TRUE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-10', 2, 101, 5,TRUE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-10', 2, 101, 2,TRUE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-12', 2, 102, 0,FALSE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-12', 2, 102, 0,FALSE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-13', 3, 103, 0,TRUE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-13', 3, 100, 0,TRUE);
insert into students values ('2022-10-13', 3, 100, 5,TRUE);
```

The Query I did to get this information is that:

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID, CLASS_ID, DATE, GRADE, ACTIVE
FROM students X
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT 1
 from students Y
 WHERE Y.STUDENT_ID = X.STUDENT_ID
    and Y.CLASS_ID = X.CLASS_ID
    and Y.DATE = X.DATE
    and Y.GRADE = 0
    and Y.ACTIVE = TRUE
```

Comment: I'm using Snowflake homologation (version 6.30.0), but when I'm using in my local, MySQL version 8.0.21